# jQuery Mobile -- how to lay out my pages

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I have an app that I'm building which is for completing a work order. The main page shows the details of the work order (site address, what needs to be done, etc.) and then there are a couple of `listviews` which show product and labour for that work order. At the start, there is no labour nor product attached to the work order, so these `listviews` are empty. When the employee is finished the work order, they can click `Add Labour` or `Add Product` to, well, add labour or product to the work order to reflect what work they've done.

I should point out that the main work order, the labour items, and the products are all distinct records in a database, all connected by the work order's primary key.

My question is about how I've laid this out. Currently, I have 3 distinct pages - one for the main work order, another for adding/editing labour and another for adding/editing product. When I say 'distinct page' I don't mean the `<div data-role="page">`, I mean, clicking "Add Labour" takes the user to a different website URL entirely.

I'm starting to question my logic in this design. Should I have all three (main, labour & product) on the same page, separated only by the `<div data-role="page">`? Then, when the user adds labour, it just takes them to that 'page' and, upon hitting "Save Labour" the main div (page) is dynamically updated (the labour `listview` gets an item added to it).

Not entirerly sure how I should have this built - I'm new to jQuery mobile.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First let me tell you, you are not doing anything wrong.

There are 2 common ways of creating jQuery Mobile applications.

1. Single HTMl / multiple pages
2. Multiple HTML files

Each way has few good and few bad sides to it. From my experience people usually choose multiple HTML files solution and it is to be expected. Single HTML / multiple pages is a new paradigm created by jQuery Mobile developers and it will take some time for people to accept it as a normal/common way.

Because you didn't say what kind of app are you creating I cant advise you which approach is the best one. Usually if you are creating a classic web page it is best to use a multiple HTML solution. In case you are creating a Phonegap mobile hybrid app it is best to use single HTML file with multiple pages (this will make sure page transitions are smooth).

If you have more questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful info. Being new to jQuery mobile (but not to webdev), I wasn't sure if the path I was taking was appropriate (multiple HTML pages). This app will be ported to a stand alone app via PhoneGap soon, so perhaps a reworking of my app is in order. The single page actually makes more sense in my head (one app=one page) but, when I first started, the idea seemed foreign. Thanks again.